# How can i login in my android application using Username and Email both(SQLite Database used)?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working on sample in which user can login using their USERNAME and EMAIL both, but in my code it is allow USERNAME only and my method for authentication is below,

```
public String getSingleEntry(String userNameOrEmail)
    {

        Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("select * from SIGNUP1 where USERNAME=?", new String[]{userNameOrEmail});


        if(cursor.getCount()<1) // UserName Not Exist
        {
            cursor.close();
            return "NOT EXIST";
        }
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String password= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PASSWORD"));
        cursor.close();
        return password;                
    }
```

And my another method that will get all user data from the SQLite database,

```
public String getUserData(String userNameOrEmail){

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from SIGNUP1 where USERNAME="+"\""+userNameOrEmail+"\"", null); 


        c.moveToFirst();
        String result="";
        String iFirstName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("FIRSTNAME"));
        String iLastName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("LASTNAME"));
        String iUserName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("USERNAME"));
        String iEmail = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("EMAIL"));
        String iPassword = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("PASSWORD"));
        String iGender = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("GENDER"));
        String iHobbies = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("HOBBIES"));

        for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            result = result + "\nName : "+iFirstName + " " +iLastName + "\nUserName : "+iUserName + "\nEmail : "+iEmail + "\nPassword : "+ iPassword + "\nYou are : " +iGender + "\nYour Hobbies : "+iHobbies;

        }
        return result;
    }
```

Is there any Query which i have to use?
I dont know how to use SELECT query using WHERE clause and have two parameters  suppose (USERNAME=? or EMAIL=?).

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, i just modified my query to "select * from SIGNUP1 where USERNAME=" +"\'"+userNameOrEmail+"\' + \" OR EMAIL=" +"\'"+ userNameOrEmail+"'", null );

Answer (score 1):

The query should be this:

```
select * from SIGNUP1 where (USERNAME='someusername' or EMAIL='someemail')
```

and you should replace the strings between ''

```
public String getSingleEntry(String userNameOrEmail,userEmail)
    {

        Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("select * from SIGNUP1 where (USERNAME=? or EMAIL=?)", new String[]{userNameOrEmail,userEmail});


    if(cursor.getCount()<1) // UserName Not Exist
    {
        cursor.close();
        return "NOT EXIST";
    }
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String password= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PASSWORD"));
    cursor.close();
    return password;                
}
```

Comment: In this instance the user would need to provide both their Username and Email. I believe (but may be wrong) that the OP is intending to allow the user to log in with either one, but not both at the same time.

Comment: He said:"I am working on sample in which user can login using their USERNAME and EMAIL both...", but your comment seems the logic way.

Comment: And then goes on to specify "suppose (USERNAME=? or EMAIL=?)." Its ambiguous at best.

Answer (score 0):

I'll point to a resource that allows you to experiment and view results of queries so you can learn:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp

Once you understand how to use the OR function you'll have no problem :).

(if you want i can post the actual answer, but i'd rather you learnt instead of copied)

EDIT: I cannot see any reason you won't be able to use OR in SQLite. There is even a [doc page](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#or_opt) for OR optimization. 
Have you tried to use it?

Comment: I am new to SQLite database and android, i know how to use this query in other SQL, but cant able to figure it out in SQLite Query format. I tried many search but didn't get any solution.